# Windows Peer to Peer Global_ Group without third party ipv6 tunnel

Tags: c++, winapi, ipv6, p2p

I have been trying to develop a peer to peer application that uses Micosoft's Peer to Peer Group library.  Basing my work on the [Creating a Group Chat Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371018(VS.85).aspx) acrticle on msdn.  This works fine for local groups and will also work for global groups if I have a thrid party tunnel adapter installed such as the gogo6 client.  However from a few things I have read it seems like I should be able to get things working through the Teredo tunnel adapter that comes built into Windows.

I have tried various things and can now access ipv6 only sites (eg ipv6.google.com) without the gogo6 tunnel running, but I can't seem to find any other peers in my global group through this method.

I have added a rule allowing trafic (including edge traversal) for the application in the Windows Firewall and also opened the following ports to incoming and outgoing trafic.

- tcp 3587
- udp 3540, 1900

From the samples I have read it seems like it should just work, but it doesn't.  I did read that to use teredo in an application you had to specificaly enable it.  The only way I have found to do this is when opening the socket, but the group api does all of that for you so I have no known way of controlling that.

Comment: Did you make sure that Teredo is turned on?

Comment: Yes teredo is on.  When I run "netsh interface teredo show state" it tells me that the state is qualified and that I have a restricted NAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Teredo clients are unreachable due to symmetric router problem. Teredo can work only behind 90% of routers. Gogo6 uses TSP which tunnels the packet to gogo6 infrastructure from where it reaches ipv6 internet.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as correct even though I kind of think there is something else going on.  Teredo has not been at all reliable for me (far more than 90% of machines failed for me) which makes Microsoft's Peer to Peer Group Library pretty much useless unless you only want local p2p.  I moved on from trying to use it (a long time ago actually).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Teredo supports IPv6 multicast.  If the Peer to Peer Group library uses multicast under the hood, I think that's the problem.  I could never find any confirmation that multicast is unsupported by Teredo; but in my own testing setsockopt(ADD_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP) would always fail when the interface ID was a Teredo interface.